# Qt Creator - Remove all UI keyboard shortcuts (QButton, QSlider etc.)

Tags: c++, qt, keyboard, shortcut, keyboard-events

I was wondering if there was a way I could remove all keyboard shortcuts from the UI so I can use the event filter to grab key commands instead.

Currently, I have this in my eventFilter() function and it does the job but it also affects the QSliders, QLineEdits and QButtons I have on there - and I don't want it to.

```cpp
bool LinkControl::eventFilter(QObject *o, QEvent *e)
{
    QKeyEvent *keyEvent = NULL;
    // qDebug() << "TYPE: " << e->type();
    switch(e->type())
    {
    case 51:
        // qDebug() << this->overrideControl;
        if(this->overrideControl == true)
        {
            keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(e);
            // this->handleKeyboardInput(true, keyEvent->key());
            // emit handleInput(true, keyEvent->key());
            this->handleKeyboardInput(true, keyEvent->key());
            // qDebug() << "PRESS: " << keyEvent->key();
        }
        this->overrideControl = !this->overrideControl;
        return true;
        break;
    case QEvent::KeyRelease:
        keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(e);
        // this->handleKeyboardInput(false, keyEvent->key());
        // emit handleInput(false, keyEvent->key());
        this->handleKeyboardInput(false, keyEvent->key());
        // qDebug() << "RELEASE: " << keyEvent->key();
        return true;
        break;
    default:
        return QMainWindow::eventFilter(o, e);
    }
}
```

For example, In my handleKeyboardInput function, I have the up arrow key increment a value and it does that but it also moves a QSlider if it's selected.

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if that helps but try adding `keyEvent->accept()` before you return true in your `QEvent::KeyRelease` branch.

Comment: Using `keyEvent->accept()` after `QEvent::KeyRelease` doesn't seem to change anything and adding it after `QEvent::KeyPress` causes the application to crash.